# How to convert a string to a hash in Ruby on Rails without using eval?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, hash

Here is the `string` which needs to convert into a `hash`.

```
"{:status => {:label => 'Status', :collection => return_misc_definitions('project_status') } }"
```

We can not use `eval` because `eval` will execute the method `return_misc_definitions('project_status')` in the string. Is there pure string operation to accomplish this conversion in Ruby/Rails?

Comment: Can you show an example, how you can create a hash and **not** call that method in the process?

Comment: If you use `eval()`, **make sure there is not user's input in the hash** you are trying to eval. Imagine a user posts a hash like this: `{ :a => User.delete_all }`!

Comment: What is the use case for this? Where do you get your string from? IMHO it is not a good idea to do this. There must be a better way to inputing the data in a safer way

Comment: the string is from data table and hash is used to compose form on .html.erb

Comment: I think this should be re-opened because the question has been restaged as without eval.  I want to turn a free text value into a hash, and of course eval is not an option.

Comment: user938363, could you delete this question?  I've re-asked it in the hopes the answer is less EVALish. I don't want it flagged as  a duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned earlier, you should use `eval`. Your point about `eval` executing `return_misc_definitions` doesn't make sense. It will be executed either way.

```
h1 = {:status => {:label => 'Status', :collection => return_misc_definitions('project_status') } }
# or 
h2 = eval("{:status => {:label => 'Status', :collection => return_misc_definitions('project_status') } }")
```

There's no functional difference between these two lines, they produce exactly the same result.

```
h1 == h2 # => true
```

Of course, if you can, don't use string represenstation of ruby hashes. Use JSON or YAML. They're much safer (don't require `eval`).

Comment: There is further processing of the hash input and use it for composing form on .html.erb. So if the eval kicks in for the method during string=>hash conversion, then we are going to have syntax error from rails.

Comment: <%= simple_form_for model,  :method => :put, :url => search_results_url  do |f| %>
      <%= fields_details.each do |field, layouts| %>
          <%= f.input field, layouts %>
      <% end %>
<% end %>